# Segmentation Fault - GNU C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gnu

I've been getting a segmentation fault that I cannot figure out. The function that causes the segmentation fault is shown below:

```
Expression *IntegerLiteral_init(int intgr) {
    Expression *the_exp = safe_alloc(sizeof(Expression));
    the_exp->type = expr_IntegerLiteral;
    the_exp->expr->intgr = intgr;
    the_exp->exec_count = 0;
    return the_exp;
}
```

An Expression is defined:

```
typedef struct {
    expr_type type;
    u_expr *expr;
    int exec_count;
} Expression;
```

u_expr and expr_type are defined:

```
typedef union {
    char *ident;
    int intgr;
} u_expr;

typedef enum {
    expr_Identifier,
    expr_IntegerLiteral
} expr_type;
```

`expr_type` is an enum of `expr_IntegerLiteral` and `expr_Identifier`.

According to GDB, the segfault is caused on the line: `the_exp->expr->intgr = intgr;`.
Strangely, it does not always cause a segfault - a segfault occurs if I call the function in this manner:

```
Expression *e = IntegerLiteral_init(0);
```

But in another part of my program, I call it using:

```
Expression *e;

...

e = IntegerLiteral_init(
    (int)strtol(num_str, (char **)NULL, 10));
```

which works without any problem. `num_str` has been parsed from some input and has the value `"0"`.

I don't understand why the context in which I call `IntegerLiteral_init()` should affect whether or not this segfault occurs, if the given `intgr` parameter is the same. If anyone could shed any light on this, I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The line

```
the_exp->expr->intgr = intgr;
```

is writing to an uninitialised pointer.  You've allocated memory for `the_exp` but not `the_exp->expr`.  The easiest fix might be to change `Expression` to have `u_expr` by value rather than pointer

```
typedef struct {
    expr_type type;
    u_expr expr;
    int exec_count;
} Expression;
```

If you can't do this, `IntegerLiteral_init` could be changed to allocate memory for `the_exp->expr`

```
Expression *IntegerLiteral_init(int intgr) {
    Expression *the_exp = safe_alloc(sizeof(Expression));
    the_exp->type = expr_IntegerLiteral;
    the_exp->expr = safe_alloc(sizeof(*the_exp->expr));
    the_exp->expr->intgr = intgr;
    the_exp->exec_count = 0;
    return the_exp;
}
```

If you try the latter approach, make sure to also free `the_exp->expr` when you free `the_exp`.

Regarding why `IntegerLiteral_init()` sometimes appears to work, accessing memory you haven't allocated results in undefined behaviour.  Sometimes you get lucky and this crashes immediately, allowing you to use a debugger to see exactly where the problem is.  Other times you are less lucky and execution of your program continues, only to crash long afterwards when some other bit of code tries to access the memory `IntegerLiteral_init()` corrupted.

Comment: You should be able to just change `Expression` to hold a `u_expr` by value then use the structure reference operator `.` in place of the structure dereference operator `->`.  i.e. `the_exp->expr.intgr = intgr;`

Comment: Thanks a million, it's working now. Not only that, you've corrected a misunderstanding I've had about unions.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you do not initialize `u_expr *expr`, it probably points to memory that will give you segmentation fault if you access it.